# Railsでコントローラーの記述を分割する方法

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller

Ruby on Railsでwebアプリを作っているのですが、コントローラーの記述が長くなってしまった場合、どのようにファイルを分割するのがいいのでしょうか？

今は、コマンドから新しくコントローラーを作って

```
class HogeController < ApplicationController
```

という形になっているやつにソースを移しているんですが、

http://qiita.com/aDaichiOta/items/3fa5bc302565bcd495a8

ここにあるみたいに

```
class HogeController < BaseController
```

としたほうがいいのでしょうか？

その場合ってコマンドからではなく直接rbを新規作成したほうがいいのですかね？
コマンドから作るとviewsの下にフォルダ掘られちゃったりしているのですが・・・。

補足として、
MVCの扱いは

http://at-grandpa.hatenablog.jp/entry/2013/11/01/072636

ここにあるあるやつの「勘違い形式」でお願いします。
あと、趣味でやっているものなので、厳密な事は求めていません。あくまで一般的に、みんなはどうやっているのかな？というところで回答をお願い致します。

Comment: MVCの話なのでmvcのタグを追加しました。

Comment: 現時点で得票数が少ないですが、はっきりと回答しにくい質問なためではないかと思います。考えられる改善案として: 1. 質問を[edit]してより具体的にする: 可能であれば、コントローラーに持たせているメソッド一覧を貼り付けるなど、コードを共有する。 2. 質問を分割する: 「ビューを持たないコントローラーを作るときはrailsコマンドを使わない方がいいか?」は別の質問として投稿する。

Comment: 後出しになってしまって申し訳ないのですが、前提として、共通する部分が全くなく、ただただ長いだけのソースを分割する場合にどうしてますか？ということです。
よろしくお願い致します。

Answer (score 5):

BaseController を作成してそちらに移動するのは、おそらく良いアイデアではないでしょう。 Hoge の代わりに Base が大きくなるオチがチラつきます。一般に継承は Hoge **IS A** Base という関係が成立するときにのみ、行うべきです。

原則は **適切に責務を分割する** です。 ([Railsでサービスとフォームを導入してみる話](http://a-suenami.hatenablog.com/entry/2013/12/06/092146)より引用)

ご自身の別の [質問](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/372/ruby-on-rails%E3%81%A7%E6%9C%AC%E5%BD%93%E3%81%AEmvc%E3%81%AE%E5%AE%9F%E8%A3%85%E6%96%B9%E6%B3%95) にもあるように、移せるものはモデルへ移すか、上記のエントリーにあるサービスやフォームを導入するということを検討してみてはどうでしょうか。

Answer (score 1):

別のアプローチとして、Controllerが肥大化する要因として「複数のRequestに対する処理を1つのController内で行っている」ことも考えられます。例えばRESTfulな設計を適用した場合、あるリソースに対する操作（CRUD）を1つのController内で定義することが一般的です。つまり、最低でもRequestを受け取るためのメソッドがCRUDに対応して4つ存在します。それぞれのメソッド内の処理が大きくなればなるほど、そのControllerは肥大化していくわけです。

もしその状態になっているのであれば、config/routes.rbを書き換えて、CRUDそれぞれに一つずつ別のControllerを作成する、という対応もありだと思います。これであれば、各Controllerの内容が単純計算で4分の1に減らせる可能性が出てきます。

そうではなく、1つのRequestに対する処理が肥大化している場合は、上の回答にあるような対策が必要でしょうね。

Answer (score 1):

一概にこの方法が良いとは言い切れないと思います。対象の状況依存ではないでしょうか。

かつて、私がやったことがある方法をあげると、以下の二つです:

- コントローラでの共通部分をベースクラスに括りだして、複数のコントローラで共有する
- コントローラで複数のモデルを操作するコードを、データを伴わないモデルとして独立させて、そこに集約し、コントローラから呼ぶ形にし、コントローラのコードを減らす

前者は、操作するモデルが複数で親子関係があり、その親にも子にも、あるいは複数の子に対しての類似した操作の場合、有効なアプローチだと思います。

後者は、複数モデルに跨いだ操作をコントローラで多くしている場合に有効です。

一方、モデルがある程度の大きさを持っていて、ユニークな操作が多い場合は、コントローラの部分に含まれるコードが増えるのは避けがたいと思います。

また、一つ気をつけたいのは、コントローラは中(当該アプリのモデルモデル)と外(ユーザや外部システム）との仲立ちをするので、制約があり、実装はどうしても縛られるという点です。この手の議論をすると、モデルのデザインが悪い、という意見が出るものですが、コントローラは、UIとは限らず、内部のモデルと外部のモデルとのインターフェースとしての役割もありますから、きれい事ばかり言えないことはあると思います。たとえば、どんなに内部のモデルがシンプルにできていても、ある程度複雑な出力をせざるえないというのはあります。

なので、見やすさと、コードの共有の程度などを勘案しながら、上記のような方法のうちから、選択してゆくしかないのではないでしょうか。

Concerns も上手に使うと良い仕掛けだと思います。ただ、コードの場所が結構離れるので、わりと見通しわるくなってしまいます。

Answer (score 0):

私も Rails 3.2 系で、BaseController を作り共通の処理を書きましたが、結局肥大化してしまい見通しが悪くなってしまいました。

そこで、Model 等でも利用している [Concerns](http://elegantbrew.tumblr.com/post/70990048275/controller-concerns-in-rails-4) という部品に分解し、必要な場合に追加を行うようにしました。

例えば、以下の様に JSON 出力が必要な例外のハンドリングを Concerns にして注入しました。

```
module ExceptionHandler
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    rescue_from Errors::BadRequest,  with: :bad_request
  end

  protected
  def bad_request(exception)
    render_exception status: __method__, debug_message: [exception.message,    exception.backtrace].join("\n")
  end

  def render_exception(args)
    status = args[:status].to_sym

    error_message = {
      status_code: Rack::Utils.status_code(status),
      status: status.to_s.humanize,
      message: args[:message] }

    respond_to do |format|
      format.json { render json: error_message, status: status }
    end
  end
end
```

独自の構造を作るときには基本的に Scaffold や Generator は利用しませんが、`rails generate controller MyContoroller`コマンドで生成を行っている場合、いくつかのオプションを付与することで生成物をスキップすることが出来ます。

```
--skip-template-engine (--no-template-engine) # View の生成をスキップする
```