# Ruby on Railsで「MVCの本当の姿」を実装する方法

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller

http://at-grandpa.hatenablog.jp/entry/2013/11/01/072636

ここで説明されている"MVCの本当の姿"というやつなんですが、これをどうやってRuby on Railsで実装するのかがさっぱり想像がつきません。

例えば"Modelの持っている加工メソッド"っていうのはapp/models/***.rbに記述するの？とか、どうやってViewからModelの状態をみて何を元に出力するの？とかなどなどです。

もうとにかく全く想像が出来ていないので、ざっくり教えて頂けたらと思います。
細かいことや厳密な事はざっくりした理解が出来てから別途質問させて頂こうと思っています。

ご回答よろしくお願い致します。

Comment: Yoichiroさんの回答で、知りたいことはカバーできていますか? まだ足りない、という場合は質問を[edit]してより具体的にするとよいと思います。「ざっくり」という要件だと答えにくいものです。上の2点の他に疑問に思っている点を共有していただけると回答者の助けになります。

Comment: それから「本当のMVCの姿」の要約もあればベストだと思います。理解が間違っていたら突っ込みをもらえますし、把握しやすくより他の人の役に立つ質問にもなります。

Comment: MVCに関する話なのでタグにmvcを追加しました。

Comment: 「本当のMVC」という質問タイトルは、流派の話になってしまいそうだったので、回答してくれるかもしれない人を遠ざけないために、リンクされている記事そのままの引用にしてみました

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> "Modelの持っている加工メソッド"っていうのはapp/models/***.rbに記述するの？

Yesです。Railsで言うMVCのModelに相当するものは、app/models の中に配置されている各Modelクラスが担当することになります。RoRの場合は、このModelクラスがActiveRecordによるO/R Mapperの役割も兼ねているので混乱の元になるのですが、基本的にはこのModelクラスに「Modelの内容を加工する処理を持つメソッド」を追加していきます。その加工処理には、他の依存Modelを生成したり、複数のModelを取得して最適な情報にまとめて返す、なども含まれます。

> どうやってViewからModelの状態をみて何を元に出力するの？

Controllerは、Modelが持つ加工処理や取得処理を呼び出した後、何らかのModelや処理結果を受け取ることになります。それらは通常Controllerのインスタンス変数にセットされますが、セットされたModelは、View、つまりRoRでいうテンプレートファイルから参照することが可能になります。つまり、Viewは業務処理結果を表すModelから画面の描画に必要な情報を引っ張ってきて、HTML内に埋めていきます。この処理のことを「Modelの状態を見て情報を出力する」という言い方をします。